# Python, WSGI, multiprocessing and shared data

Tags: python, multiprocessing, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I am a bit confused about multiproessing feature of mod_wsgi and about a general design of WSGI applications that would be executed on WSGI servers with multiprocessing ability.

Consider the following directive:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess example processes=5 threads=1
```

If I understand correctly, mod_wsgi will spawn 5 Python (e.g. CPython) processes and any of these processes can receive a request from a user.

The documentation says that:

> Where shared data needs to be visible to all application instances, regardless of which child process they execute in, and changes made to
>   the data by one application are immediately available to another,
>   including any executing in another child process, an external data
>   store such as a database or shared memory must be used. Global
>   variables in normal Python modules cannot be used for this purpose.

But in that case it gets really heavy when one wants to be sure that an app runs in any WSGI conditions (including multiprocessing ones).

For example, a simple variable which contains the current amount of connected users - should it be process-safe read/written from/to memcached, or a DB or (if such out-of-the-standard-library mechanisms are available) shared memory?

And will the code like

```
counter = 0

@app.route('/login')
def login():
    ...
    counter += 1
    ...

@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    ...
    counter -= 1
    ...

@app.route('/show_users_count')
def show_users_count():
    return counter
```

behave unpredictably in multiprocessing environment?

Thank you!

Comment: Quoting: "a simple variable which contains the current amount of connected users".  This is HTTP, there is no notion of a "connected" user, so such a count cannot be "simple".  (For example, users can log out by forgetting whatever token you gave them -- e.g. by clearing their browser cookies).

Comment: Meaning the users that the application treats as 'connected' ones e.g. by last HTTP session timestamp + 10 mins.

Comment: +1 on Andre's comment, but while I agree about the inherent difficulties of session counting, I think this has more to do with good web design than the specific multiprocessing/shared data question at hand. Another issue is that there is no code in place to make sure counter is being read from, updated, and written back in an orderly manner (to my knowledge, += 1 is not an atomic operation in python...). Some kind of locking is needed.

Comment: Guys, indeed, locking is needed and this is just a simple example. Consider `a` wrapped by descriptor with thread-safe operations. The question is about multiprocessing, NOT multithreading.

Comment: @marr75: Note that the comment was tongue in cheek, I don't think OP is actually expecting to use this in the real world :-)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There are several aspects to consider in your question.

First, the interaction between apache MPM's and mod_wsgi applications. If you run the mod_wsgi application in embedded mode (no `WSGIDaemonProcess` needed, `WSGIProcessGroup %{GLOBAL}`) you inherit multiprocessing/multithreading from the apache MPM's. This should be the fastest option, and you end up having multiple processes and multiple threads per process, depending on your MPM configuration. On the contrary if you run mod_wsgi in daemon mode, with `WSGIDaemonProcess <name> [options]` and `WSGIProcessGroup <name>`, you have fine control on multiprocessing/multithreading at the cost of a small [overhead](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/PerformanceEstimates).

Within a single apache2 server you may define zero, one, or more named `WSGIDaemonProcess`es, and each application can be run in one of these processes (`WSGIProcessGroup <name>`) or run in embedded mode with `WSGIProcessGroup %{GLOBAL}`.

You can check multiprocessing/multithreading by inspecting the `wsgi.multithread` and `wsgi.multiprocess` variables.

With your configuration `WSGIDaemonProcess example processes=5 threads=1` you have 5 independent processes, each with a single thread of execution: no global data, no shared memory, since you are not in control of spawning subprocesses, but mod_wsgi is doing it for you. To share a global state you already listed some possible options: a DB to which your processes interface, some sort of file system based persistence, a daemon process (started outside apache) and socket based IPC.

As pointed out by Roland Smith, the latter could be implemented using a high level API by [`multiprocessing.managers`](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#managers): outside apache you create and start a `BaseManager` server process

```
m = multiprocessing.managers.BaseManager(address=('', 12345), authkey='secret')
m.get_server().serve_forever()
```

and inside you apps you `connect`:

```
m = multiprocessing.managers.BaseManager(address=('', 12345), authkey='secret')
m.connect()
```

The example above is dummy, since `m` has no useful method registered, but [here](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-remote-manager) (python docs) you will find how to create and *proxy* an object (like the `counter` in your example) among your processes.

A final comment on your example, with `processes=5 threads=1`. I understand that this is just an example, but in real world applications I suspect that performance will be comparable with respect to `processes=1 threads=5`: you should go into the intricacies of sharing data in multiprocessing only if the expected performance boost over the 'single process many threads' model is significant.

Comment: You're welcome! I edited my answer to make clear that the discussion applies to applications run by mod_wsgi, and not to mod_wsgi as a whole, as my wording may have suggested.

Answer (score 4):

From the docs on processes and threading for wsgi:

> When Apache is run in a mode whereby there are multiple child processes, each child process will contain sub interpreters for each WSGI application.

This means that in your configuration, 5 processes with 1 thread each, there will be 5 interpreters and no shared data. Your counter object will be unique to each interpreter. You would need to either build some custom solution to count sessions (one common process you can communicate with, some kind of persistence based solution, etc.) OR, and this is definitely my recommendation, use a prebuilt solution (Google Analytics and Chartbeat are fantastic options).

I tend to think of using globals to share data as a big form of global abuse. It's a bug well and portability issue in most of the environments I've done parallel processing in. What if suddenly your application was to be run on multiple virtual machines? This would break your code no matter what the sharing model of threads and processes.

Comment: Here's a page on seeing your site traffic through the chartbeat api (if you need to use this data programmatically): http://chartbeat.com/docs/api/explore/#endpoint=live/summary/v3/

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `multiprocessing`, there are [multiple ways](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) to share data between processes. [Values](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Value) and [Arrays](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Array) only work if processes have a parent/child relation (they are shared by inheriting). If that is not the case, use a [`Manager`](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#managers) and [`Proxy`](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#proxy-objects) objects.

Comment: What if the data is not `pickle` serializable? Like: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69430747/6907424