# Disable mod_wsgi starting new threads for Flask script

Tags: python, multithreading, apache, flask, mod-wsgi

I'm setting up a RPI3 to control/measure external electronics. It uses an Apache2 server alongside mod_wsgi that runs Flask. All of the code for the controls are in a separate class called **Timer**, that gets initialized in the __init__.py Flask script. The main loop for the controls is on a different thread.

Couldn't find this functionality in the documentations, but from the experiences it seems like that the server runs on the same __init__.py as long as it gets requests sparsely. If the script is busy when a new request comes then the server starts a new one of it on a separate thread. When this happens, the original instance of the **Timer** class is "lost in the memory", because the current script that handles the requests from there on doesn't know about it.

My solution was for a long time to write all the information about the running object to a json file, and set up both the **Timer** class and the __init__.py to read/write into it. Which is a bit dodgy in my opinion. Surely this has been worked around before.

So i would like to do either one of these two things:

- disable this functionality so the same script handles the requests always, no matter what. (This seems like something that will produce a lot of errors)
- (Preferred) Access the "lost" object (and thread running the measurement) in the memory and control it directly from the script on the new thread.

Are these possible to do?

Here is the simplified code.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import time
import threading

class Timer:
    def __init__(self):
        #setup variables
        pass

    def mainloop(self):
        while True:
            data = readSensor()
            writeFile(data)
            time.sleep(5)


app = Flask(__name__)

t = Timer()

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def homepage():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return render_template("main.html")
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template("main.html")


@app.route('/_submit')
def submit():
    t = threading.Thread(target=t.mainloop)
    t.start

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: Are you using mod_wsgi daemon mode? If you were it defaults to all requests being handled in the one process. Sounds like you may be using Apache/mod_wsgi in embedded mode, where number of processes/threads dictated by Apache and so requests could be handled in different processes. Show your mod_wsgi configuration.

Comment: It could also be a case that you should just be using thread local data so each thread has its own timer instance. Or that you should be maintaining a data structure keyed by some sort of request ID or session ID. Your description is a bit confusing so hard to suggest anything. Maybe show a bit of code as to how you are storing the timer instance.

Comment: See this thread and let us know if it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12715139/python-wsgi-multiprocessing-and-shared-data

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton I uploaded a simple example to show what i want to accomplish (might be completely incorrect to do it like this). Came across your blog about Apache embedded and daemon mode. Very thorough! Set it up to run in daemon mode, but only managed to achieve what i wanted when i set both the processes and threads to 1 max.

Comment: @TarunLalwani tried it and it works so far when testing with just a couple lines of code. Feels bit of an overkill to run a separate server for one class, but much better than writing everything to files.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try the approach discussed on

[Python, WSGI, multiprocessing and shared data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12715139/python-wsgi-multiprocessing-and-shared-data)

Basically you want shared data across threads/processes