# Multiprocessing dictionary update flask web server on WSGI

Tags: python, flask, wsgi

I want to synchronize a Python dictionary running on my Flask application, which will be hosted on WSGI.

I have the following code

```
from flask import Flask

sessions = {}

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def serve():

    session_id = get_sessions_id() # function that returns session id
    if session_id in sessions:
        return 'Exist'

    sessions[session_id] = 'New'

    return sessions[session_id]
```

I want to run this flask application on WSGI and sync the `sessions` dictionary between all the WSGI processes, how can I do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python, WSGI, multiprocessing and shared data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12715139/python-wsgi-multiprocessing-and-shared-data)

Comment: @Dimitar, Actually no, it is not provide an relevant answer for my issue